# SQLServer - how to move tables between instances?

Tags: sql-server

I'm not very familiar with SQLServer and, thus, I inadvertently created a database in a fashion I thought it would work.

In SQL Management Studio, I right clicked the instance and created a `xpto` database, so all my tables are `xpto.tableName` instead of `dbo.tableName`.

Should I expect performance issues?

Also, is there a *somewhat safe* way to move tables from `xpto` to `dbo`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all if your object names are `xpto.tablename` you probably created a schema not a new database.

Schemas are the containers for objects such as tables.  Databases contain schemas.  So the naming format is `databasename.schemaname.tablename`.

Assuming that is correct it's very easy to change the schema that owns your tables using `ALTER SCHEMA`.

```
ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER schemaname.tablename
```

This will transfer TableName into the dbo schema.  Or a little closer to your specific case

```
ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER xpto.tablename
```

If in fact your tables are in the wrong database you can move them by using something like this:

```
USE correctDBName
SELECT * INTO xpto.dbo.TableName FROM tablename
```

You'll then want to generate any indexes, constraints, permissions etc and apply them in the correct database.

**Edit**

Here is a query you can use to construct the commands to transfer all the tables from the xpto schema to the dbo schema.

```
SELECT 'ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER xpto.' + quotename(tables.name)
FROM sys.tables
JOIN sys.schemas
    ON sys.tables.schema_id = sys.schemas.schema_id
WHERE sys.schemas.name = 'xpto'
```

Comment: thanks! It's exactly so! I have really created a schema. Can I do something like `ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER xpto.*` or will I have to do it for each table, even though the latter might be more advisable?

Comment: I believe you will have to do it one table at a time.  Easy enough to construct dynamic SQL to handle it for you however.

Answer (score 2):

The basic command is

`ALTER SCHEMA NewSchema TRANSFER OldSchema.ObjectName`

so your command will be as below :

`ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER xpto.Table_Name`

> Should I expect performance issues?

No there would be no perf issues. But its a [good practice](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix) to use `schema.objectname`

TO do it for all your user tables, run below code, review it and then run the output :

```
select Schema_name(schema_id) as [Old_SCHEMA_NAME]
    ,object_NAME(object_id) as [Object_Name]
    ,'ALTER SCHEMA [dbo] TRANSFER '+ quotename(Schema_name(schema_id))+'.'+ quotename(object_NAME(object_id)) as [Command To Change schema]
from sys.objects
where Schema_name(schema_id) = 'xpto' -- change here !!
and is_ms_shipped = 0
and type in ('U', 'P', 'V')
order by object_NAME(object_id)
-- U = User table, P = Stored procs & V = Views
```

> I right clicked the instance and created a xpto database, so all my tables are xpto.tableName instead of dbo.tableName

Thats not possible. The user that you are using is having default schema of `xpto`. Just change the default schema of the user to `dbo` so any new objects will be having a default schema of `dbo`.